# Why must a domain be nonzero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, integral-domain

I recently stumbled across the following definition:

> A ring $\mathcal R$ is called *domain*, if $\mathcal R$ is nonzero and $0$ is the only
>   zero divisor in $\mathcal R$.

I'm wondering why the condition *$\mathcal R$ is nonzero* is even necessary, since for $\mathcal R = 0, 0$ already is no zero divisor $(\not\exists y\in \mathcal R, y \not= 0: 0\cdot y = 0)$. So the zero ring wouldn't be a domain without the extra part in the definition anyway.
 What am I missing?

Comment: IMHO, every definition in maths comes with a purpose/motivation.  We *want* to do cancellation on both sides on an equality, so we definite *integral domain*.  It *doesn't* make sense to do cancellation on $\cal{R}=\{0\}$, so the definition excludes this case.  I *think* domain is the noncommutative counterpart of integral domain.

Comment: Every finite domain is a field. The zero ring has wildly different properties to the "other" finite fields. It's similar to how $1$ is not a prime number.

Comment: One usually wants $1\ne 0$. At any rate, it is required in commutative algebra.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes. I do understand, that we don't want $\mathcal R = 0$ to be a called a domain, but I'm confused, why this is necessary to include in the definition (since the definition without this additional condition, would exclude zero ring, already).

Comment: @quasi Thank you! That answers my question. The other comments answered, why we don't want the zero ring to be a domain, but didn't state why the condition "$0$ is the only zero divisor in $\mathcal R$ isn't enough".

Comment: Actually,  In the zero ring, zero is actually _not_ a zero-divisor. In all other rings, zero _is_ a zero-divisor. So the author first excludes the zero ring, and then excludes rings where zero is not the only zero-divisor. Nothing wrong with the author's definition.

Comment: @quasi Yes, that's why I think that $\mathcal R \neq 0$ is redundant.

Comment: Redundant perhaps, but clear. The author wants to emphasize that the zero ring is excluded, rather than making it a consequence of the other condition.

Comment: @quasi Thank you. I thought that it can't be that simple. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, I'll just leave it as comments.

Answer (score 2):

With the usual definition, it's convenient to have that an ideal in a commutative ring $I \subset R$ is a prime ideal iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. We don't want to consider the whole ring as a prime ideal for the similar reasons that we don't want $1$ to be a prime number. (And of course we want integral domains to be the commutative domains.) It would also mess up algebraic geometry if the whole ring was a prime ideal.

More general theorems break down if we allow the zero ring as an integral domain: integral domains always have a field of fractions that we can embed them into, but for the zero ring, the only possibility is the zero ring itself. Now you could say that just shifts the question to why the zero ring is not a field, but there are multiple reasons for that:

- The set of non-zero elements is empty, so it doesn't form a group.
- For example linear algebra over the zero ring looks very different (and boring) compared to other fields
- In a classification that allows one to write certain rings as a product over fields or something similar (e.g. the Artin-Wedderburn theorem) we would explicitly need to exclude the zero ring to retain uniqueness.

See also [too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways in which one can think of a ring as having "components" — domains are the rings that have one component, and the zero ring is the ring that has zero components.

For example, every ring $R$ has a *total ring of fractions* $Q(R)$: the localization formed by inverting the multiplicative subset of non-zero divisors.

In the case that $R$ is a Noetherian reduced ring, then $Q(R)$ is a product of finitely many fields, and:

- $R$ is the zero ring if and only if $Q(R)$ is a product of zero fields (i.e. is the zero ring)
- $R$ is a domain if and only if $Q(R)$ is a product of one field (i.e. is a field)